# I've made an HTML table with editable cells. When I edit a cell I need the row and the rows below it to recalculate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

```
<table cellspacing="0" width="80%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Invoice amount
        </th>
        <th>
            Interest rate
        </th>
        <th>
            Interest amount
        </th>
        <th>
            Amortization
        </th>
        <th>
            Capital balance
        </th>       
    </tr>
</thead>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <div contenteditable class="editor">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InvoiceAmount)
        </div>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <div contenteditable class="editor">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InterestRate)
        </div>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <div contenteditable class="editor">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InterestAmount)
        </div>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <div contenteditable class="editor">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amortization)
        </div>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <div contenteditable class="editor">
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PresentValue)
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

In the previous view you add numbers into textboxes and click on a button to calculate which brings you to this table. The calculation method is in my CalculationController. I want this table to be like in excel, the rows should be dependent of each other.

For example, when I edit the "interest rate" I just need to update that row and the rows beneath. Not those in the past. Its meant to be an annuity calculation.

Thankful for any help.

Comment: I'm sorry but cannot see any of your own attempt. Could you post it?!

Comment: At the moment the best answer to this would be "use JavaScript."  It's a broad question, so it's a broad answer.  Essentially your JavaScript would bind to the change events (or even keypress events?) of your inputs and re-calculate the other inputs based on the updated state.

Comment: So with jquery could I use:
`$( "#TDID" ).change(function() {
  // somehow call a method in controller that recalculates the row?
});`
Im using MVC 4 by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript (possibly using a library like jQuery) would make this pretty easy. For example, the following makes a calculation based on the Invoice Amount cell (assuming you've given it an ID of InvoiceAmount). It does so as someone types into that cell. Then it updates the value of another element with the result:

```
    $("#InvoiceAmount").bind('keyup keydown keypress',function()
        {
            // Your calculations here
            var invoiceMultiplied = $(this).val()*5;
            // Update another element with the result
            $('#AnotherElement').html(invoiceMultiplied);
        }
    );
```

If your calculations are extremely complex or you need to access other data that's not loaded on the page, then you will want to consider AJAX with your server side language of choice.

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/technotarek/QSv4h/

Comment: Thanks for the reply @technoTarek ive tried it in jsfiddle but it didnt work. Am I getting something wrong?[ http://jsfiddle.net/c5EVc/ ]

Comment: Note that I'm doing any kind of validation, so if you put something  other than a numeric value into the input, you'll have problems (e.g., because you can't multiply a string by 5).

Comment: RE my last comment, meant to say "Note that I'm NOT doing any kind of validation...". Did this work for you?

Comment: Great, if you wouldn't mind, please accept the answer then. Thanks in advance.